# Will DLC work on my user on ps4?

Tags: ps4, psn

My roommate has a PS4 with PS+ and downloaded Bloodborne, we have different users, and I play the game on my user but I want to buy the DLC, if I buy it will it work on my user with a different PSN account that has no PS+?

Or do I need to buy it and download on my friend's user and account?

If I buy on his account will I be able to play on my user? Sorry if this got a little bit confusing.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to buy DLC without owning a base game. I cannot find any official documentation regarding it, but I found [this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/PS4/comments/2epv86/can_you_download_dlc_without_owning_the_game/) and tried myself to add DLC to shopping cart in store. So you can buy it on your own account.

Both of you will be able to play DLC - this is how sharing works for local accounts. However, if your roommate will ever decide to stop paying for PS+ you will lose access to game itself.

If you purchase DLC on his account everything will be the same - both of you will have access to game and DLC until PS+ is active.